# Scheduling Cover Photo change on a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-timeline, cover

The ideia is to automatically swap the Cover Photo to feature a different TV program each single day.

Am I able to do that? If so, could you please explain me how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can not programatically change the cover photo (at this stage).

Similarly, you can't change someones profile picture through an application.

---

You **will** be able to upload a photo to the cover_photo's album however - so you can do that and then simply instruct your users on how to select it as their chosen cover photo.

Answer (score 1):

There was a free facebook application that allowed users to schedule cover photo changes at different intervals. It is called PageCovery. Since may 2018 this app is discontinued.

Comment: Do you have a hyperlink to this application?